# How to structure custom binary protocol TCP request

Tags: c#, tcp, protocols

I'm working on a code challenge which, in short, provides a server that encodes/decodes the data sent in the request. It is a TCP/IP server with the following custom binary request/response structures:

[image: request/response structures]

I need to create a desktop client that will send requests and receive responses, and display data accordingly. I'm having trouble understanding how the request would be formed, and how I would send the request to the TCP/IP server (using C#). Could someone provide perhaps an example of what this might look like?

Comment: so you are having trouble with the whole thing?

Comment: after googling "C# byte array"  and "C# send bytes TCP"  where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at understanding how the request should look. If I had an example request I might be able to figure it out. e.g. if I was trying to use "test string" as the data, what would that look like in request form?

Answer (score 2):

not sure about your checksum, but constructing a packet would look something like

```
        byte[] CreatePacket(string s, Operation op)
        {
            var packet = new List<byte>();
            packet.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16) 0x1092));
            packet.Add(1);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            packet.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32) (9 + data.Length)));
            packet.Add((byte) (op == Operation.Encode ? 1 : 2));
            packet.AddRange(data);
            packet.Add(CheckSum(packet));
            return packet.ToArray();
        }
```

given

```
    enum Operation
    {
        Encode,
        Decode,
    }
```

and

```
server.Send(CreatePacket("test string", Operation.Encode))
```

Also with the checksum spec...

```
        byte CheckSum(List<byte> packet)
        {
            return (byte)(packet.Select((b, i) => (value: b, index: i))
                .Sum(o => (o.value & (1 << (o.index % 8))) > 0 ? 1 :0) % 256);
        }
```

Comment: FWIW,

The checksum is calculated by looping through each byte and evaluating a bit of the byte in a specific position depending on the byte being evaluated.  This checksum is specifically 

 - For the 1st byte in the Request / Response, evaluate the bit in the 1st position. If the bit being evaluated is 1 then increment the checksum by 1.  If the bit being evaluated is 0 do nothing.  
 - For the 2nd byte in the Request / Response, evaluate the bit in the 2nd position. If the bit being evaluated is 1 then increment the checksum by 1.  If the bit being evaluated is 0 do nothing.

Comment: also, does your solution take into consideration the fact that the length aspect expects little endian UInt32?

Comment: by default it is little endian.  But it can change on other platforms ( I'm not sure there is a platfrom that is different)  you can see what it is on your platform with something like `Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);`

Comment: also, not sure about the checksum definition, I made some assumptions so may or may not work,